# Horizontal line indicating axis value for a single point in Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to use candlestick or line chart from Google Charts.
Is there any way to draw a horizontal line from a rightmost point of graph (last value) to the Y axis, with Y value shown on axis? 
I just want to clearly display Y value of "last" point on a graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Google Charts rendered using HTML5/SVG, you could consider the following solution to render a *custom horizontal axis*:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales'],
        ['2004', 1000],
        ['2005', 1170],
        ['2006', 660],
        ['2007', 1030]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    drawAdditionalHAxis(chart, data);  //render custom axis (line & label) for the last value 
}


function drawAdditionalHAxis(chart,dataTable){
    var layout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartArea = layout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();

    var svg = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    var lastVal = dataTable.getValue(dataTable.getNumberOfRows()-1,1);
    var yLoc = layout.getYLocation(lastVal);
    svg.appendChild(createLine(chartArea.left,yLoc,chartArea.width + chartArea.left,yLoc,'#cccccc',1)); // axis line
    svg.appendChild(createText(chartArea.left - 40 ,yLoc + 5,'Arial','13',lastVal)); // axis label 
}





function createLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, w) {
    var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    line.setAttribute('x1', x1);
    line.setAttribute('y1', y1);
    line.setAttribute('x2', x2);
    line.setAttribute('y2', y2);
    line.setAttribute('stroke', color);
    line.setAttribute('stroke-width', w);
    return line;
}

function createText(x, y, fontFamily, fontSize,value) {
    var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
    text.setAttribute('x', x);
    text.setAttribute('y', y);
    text.setAttribute('font-family', fontFamily);
    text.setAttribute('font-size', fontSize);
    text.innerHTML = value;
    return text;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 640px; height: 480px"></div>
```

Comment: So I have to do it myself then. It's so strange such a basic functionality is not included in Google Charts. Who wouldn't want to show a value for some point on a graph every now and then?